# Using world map plugin in Grafana with Prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus, world-map

I’m using Grafana with Prometheus and want to use the World Map plugin: the idea is that I have several geopoints with some values that I want to visualize with World Map.

Data example that is being returned from prometheus has the following structure:
[image: Prometheus structure]

Also I edit probes.json and 100% shure that World Map plugin is using my customized probes.json file. Here is the part of it:

```
…
{
“key”: “taipei”,
“latitude”: 25.105497,
“longitude”: 121.597366,
“name”: “Taipei”
},
{
“key”: “tokyo”,
“latitude”: 35.652832,
“longitude”: 139.839478,
“name”: “Tokyo”
},
{
“key”: “y1918”,
“latitude”: 53.717564,
“longitude”: 91.429317,
“name”: “ABAKAN”
},
{
“key”: “szvpz”,
“latitude”: 44.993166,
“longitude”: 41.103135,
“name”: “ARMAVIR”
},
{
“key”: “ugkz7”,
“latitude”: 64.5562829,
“longitude”: 40.5962809,
“name”: “ARKHANGELSK”
},
{
“key”: “v04pt”,
“latitude”: 46.3432541,
“longitude”: 47.933211,
“name”: “ASTRAKHAN”
},
…
```

Here is the Grafana setup:
[image: Grafana setup]

I get no error but there is no circles on the map, what am I doing wrong? What data should I provide to grafana from prometheus if it is the reason of the problem I’m having? Adding Legend format “{{geohash}}” doesn’t help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was given an answer in [grafana community forum](https://community.grafana.com/t/prometheus-grafana-worldmap-not-working/1997/14) and going to repost it here, so people could find if they need it.
So it apears that World Map Plugin for Grafana with Prometheus is supporting geohash, despite the fact that it is not written in doc.

To make it work you have to enter corect settings, the data that I provide from Prometheus is correct. First you need to format metrics as a table:

[image: metrics]
In the Worldmap pannel you should enter following data:

[image]

For ES Metric Field to work with geohash you allways should enter "Value", ES Location Name Field is where do you went the points name from, and ES geo_point Filed where do you get the data geohash value from. Data I'm getting from Prometheus you can find in a question part.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [World Panel documentation](https://github.com/grafana/worldmap-panel#map-data-options), geohashes are not directly supported with Prometheus as a datasource, only countries and states.

But you can use them anyway if you also provide a custom json file with the location data to resolve them.

First, configure your Prometheus datasource and enter your query. Make sure you have the legend set to `{{ whatever your geohash field in the Prometheus timeseries is }}`. If I did not have the legend, set then nothing would display.

Now go to the "Worldmap" tab and set the drop-down to "json endpoint" and point the URL to wherever you keep your json file with the mappings.

Make sure it's valid json and make sure that the webserver sets correct CORS headers so your browser can load the file (confirm via the network inspector tab).

Now refresh the map and you should see your data points.

Comment: As I know now Grafana with Prometheus does support geohash, but it is not described in docs. I'll post my answer in a while.

Comment: Even this solution didn't work for me, I'm gonna give my bounty to you as it is the only answer.

Comment: Thank you, that's generous. I wonder why this didn't work for you. I got it to work with Prometheus 2.2.1, Grafana 5.0 and the latest version of the panel plugin. Sample data I had Prometheus ingest was in the format of `job_location{location="szvpz"} 33`

Comment: I'm not very good at JS so I can't tell exacttly where is the problem, I can tell that, on debufing I was getting empty data couldn't find the reason